# How to add radio buttons dynamically in Windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I need to add radio buttons dynamically in my windows form and in horizontal mode.
[image: Sample]

```
for (int i = 0; i <= r.Count; i++)
{
RadioButton rdo = new RadioButton();
rdo.Name = "id";
rdo.Text = "Name";
rdo.ForeColor = Color.Red;
rdo.Location = new Point(5, 30 );
this.Controls.Add(rdo);
}
```

Comment: great/ What have you tried

Comment: does something like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e78f393d-1ae0-4f0d-b488-d2c453219220/how-to-create-radio-buttons-dynamically-in-a-groupbox?forum=winforms) answer your question?

Comment: @MarkC. I used this same link but it displays the radio button vertically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
FlowLayoutPanel pnl = new FlowLayoutPanel();
pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    pnl.Controls.Add(new RadioButton() { Text = "RadioButton" + i });
}

this.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

You could also add the `FlowLayoutPanel` in the designer and leave that part out in the code.

To get the selected `RadioButton` use a construct like this:

```
RadioButton rbSelected = pnl.Controls
                         .OfType<RadioButton>()
                         .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

To use this the `FlowLayoutPanel` needs to be known in the calling method. So either add it to the `Form` in the designer (Thats what I would prefer) or create it as an instance member of the form and add it at runtime (this has no benefit).

Comment: No matter. Please mark as correct answer if this was the solution to your problem

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get the selected radio button ID on save button click? @Romano Zumbe

Comment: can you please suggest

Comment: Just for clarity, Romano's answer now shows how to get the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
//This is my dynamic data list
List<ItemType> itemTypeData = new List<ItemType>()

RadioButton[] itemTypes = new RadioButton[ItemType.Count];
int locationX = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ItemType.Count; i++)
{
     var type = ItemType[i];
     itemTypes[i] = new RadioButton
     {
         Name = type.Code,
         Text = type.Code,
         AutoSize = true,
         Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 11F, FontStyle.Regular),
         Location = new Point(156 + locationX, 88),
     };
                
     this.Controls.Add(itemTypes[i]);
     locationX += 80;
}
```

This works fine for me