# c#: How to add radio buttons dynamically in two rows with a fixed window size

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, radio-group

I try to add radio buttons dynamically to a Windows Forms application in two rows (there is always an even amount of radio buttons in my case). I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783473/how-to-add-radio-buttons-dynamically-in-windows-form), which helps me to understand how to generally add radio buttons.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        FlowLayoutPanel pnl = new FlowLayoutPanel();

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        void radioButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Radio Button", "Click");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                pnl.Controls.Add(new RadioButton() { Text = "" + i });
                pnl.Controls[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.radioButtonHandler);
            }

            this.Controls.Add(pnl);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The problem is, the mentioned question doesn't cover the following questions:

1. How to set the distance between the radio buttons?
2. How to create a second row with a defined distance below the first row?
3. How to fix the buttons and insert a horizontally scroll bar if the buttons need more space than the current window has?
4. OPTIONAL: In my case the two radio buttons along the vertical line always belong together. Is it possible to automatically deselect the upper or lower one, if the other one is selected?  There must only be one selected radio button per vertical line. Maybe with a radio group?

Comment: Do you want to remove spaces?

Comment: I would like to define the space size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
panel.AutoScroll = true;
panel.WrapContents= true;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
   panel .Controls.Add(new RadioButton()
        {
            Text = "" + i,
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom
                   | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right,
            AutoSize = true,
            Margin = //your styles,
        });
   panel .Controls[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.radioButtonHandler);
}
```

setting AnchorStyles help you to keep your controls aligned and by proerties like padding or size you can define size of you elements if all radiobuttons ahave same width you can use size attribute.if they dont have a same size its better to use AnchorStyles .

Comment: Sorry but I have problems to reproduce your example... In my case there is no radio button at all in my forms window.

Comment: Ok, adding `this.Controls.Add(panel);` did the trick. But It doesn't seem to produce the right output. 1. When I reduce the window size, there doesn't appear any scroll bar. The radio buttons disappear behind the window border. 2. Depending on the rb size, there are more than 2 rb's on top of each other. 3. It seems, that all rb's are belong together and not just the two at a vertical line.

Comment: @PascalS have you set WrapContents= true?Also for resizing you should set anchor for panel.and this code is for all of your controls you can change radiovutton to any type.

Answer (score 1):

```
FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
flp.Size = new Size(950, 100);
flp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
flp.AutoScroll = true;

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
    rb.Text = i.ToString();
    rb.AutoSize = false;
    rb.Size = new Size(100, 25);
    flp.Controls.Add(rb);
}

this.Controls.Add(flp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work as expected 1. When I reduce the window size, there does not appear any scroll bar. The radio buttons disappear behind the window border. 2. Depending on the rb size, there are more than 2 rb's on top of each other. 3. It seems, that all rb's are belong together and not just the two at a vertical line.